# Loader not updating the list on screen

Tags: android, runtime-error, loader

Loader not updating the list on the screen.the list only updated when I press the button and `sampleLoader.onContentChanged()` called. also their is some problem with the broadcast receiver. When I changed configuration first time it gives this error below.and also list updated on configuration change when activity restarts. but if keep the activity open the data that service add in background dosn't updated in list.

**Code: Main activity implementing LoaderCallback**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<DemoItem>>,ServiceCallbacks {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivityFragment";
private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;
Context context;
private UpdateServices myService;
private boolean bound = false;
MySQLiteHelper m;
SampleLoader sampleLoader;
CustomAdapter customAdapter;
ListView mList;
ArrayList<DemoItem> allList;
Button b1,b2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /**
     * This condition check saved instance if any and assign it
     */
   /*if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        sampleLoader = (SampleLoader) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("ObjectA");
        // check mObjectA == mObjectA.getObjectBList().get(0).getParent();

    }*/
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    m = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
    /**
     * This method initialize the Loader
     */
  sampleLoader = (SampleLoader) getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null,this);

    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    allList = m.getAllItems();
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, allList);
    mList.setAdapter(customAdapter);
 final    ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // cast the IBinder and get MyService instance
            UpdateServices.LocalBinder binder = (UpdateServices.LocalBinder) service;
            myService = binder.getService();
            bound = true;
            myService.setCallbacks(MainActivity.this); // register
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            bound = false;
        }
    };
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            add();
           // startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateServices.class));

        }
    });

    if(!isMyServiceRunning(UpdateServices.class)) {
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateServices.class));
    }
   // Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateServices.class);
    //bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           // stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateServices.class));
            if (bound) {
                myService.setCallbacks(null); // unregister
                unbindService(serviceConnection);
                bound = false;
            }
        }
    });

}

public void add() {

    DemoItem d = new DemoItem();
    d.set("Fifty5Bytes", "Company");
    m.addItem(d);

    sampleLoader.onContentChanged();
}


@Override
public Loader<List<DemoItem>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader");
    sampleLoader = new SampleLoader(this);
    return sampleLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<DemoItem>> loader, List<DemoItem> cursor) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished " + cursor.size());
    allList.clear();
    allList.addAll(m.getAllItems());
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mList.setSelection(allList.size() - 1);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<DemoItem>> loader) {
   // sampleLoader = null;
    Log.i(TAG, "onLoaderReset");
}
/* @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("ObjectA", sampleLoader);
}*/


@Override
public void doSomething() {
    Log.i("do something","do something called");
    sampleLoader.onContentChanged();
}
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    try {
        super.onStop();
    }catch (Exception e){}
    Log.i(TAG, "on stop called");
}

/** Lifecycle method: The final call received before the activity is destroyed. */
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    try{
    super.onDestroy();}
    catch (Exception e){}

    Log.i(TAG,"on destroy called");
}
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

**Loader Class have**

```
public class SampleLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<DemoItem>> implements Serializable {

public static final String TAG = "SampleLoader";

/** We hold a reference to the Loader’s data here.*/
private List<DemoItem> mData;

Context ctx;

public SampleLoader(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx);
    this.ctx = ctx;
    ctx.registerReceiver(mObserver, new IntentFilter("my-event"));
}

@Override
public List<DemoItem> loadInBackground() {
    // This method is called on a background thread and should generate a
    // new set of data to be delivered back to the client.

    MySQLiteHelper mySQLiteHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(ctx);
    List<DemoItem> allItems = mySQLiteHelper.getAllItems();

    Log.i(TAG,"Size : " + allItems.size());

    return allItems;
}

@Override
public void deliverResult(List<DemoItem> data) {
    if (isReset()) {
        // The Loader has been reset;
        releaseResources(data);
        return;
    }

    // Hold a reference to the old data so it doesn't get garbage collected.
    // We must protect it until the new data has been delivered.
    List<DemoItem> oldData = mData;
    mData = data;

    if (isStarted()) {
        // If the Loader is in a started state, deliver the results to the
        // client. The superclass method does this for us.
        super.deliverResult(data);
    }

    // Invalidate the old data as we don't need it any more.
    if (oldData != null && oldData != data) {
        releaseResources(oldData);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (mData != null) {
        // Deliver any previously loaded data immediately.
        deliverResult(mData);
    }

    if (takeContentChanged() || mData == null) {
        // When the observer detects a change, it should call onContentChanged()
        // on the Loader, which will cause the next call to takeContentChanged()
        // to return true. If this is ever the case (or if the current data is
        // null), we force a new load.
        forceLoad();
        Intent intent = new Intent("my-event");
        intent.putExtra("message", "message");
        getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStopLoading() {
    // The Loader is in a stopped state, so we should attempt to cancel the
    // current load (if there is one).
    cancelLoad();

    // Note that we leave the observer as is. Loaders in a stopped state
    // should still monitor the data source for changes so that the Loader
    // will know to force a new load if it is ever started again.
}

@Override
protected void onReset() {
    // Ensure the loader has been stopped.
    onStopLoading();
    Log.i("Onreset","Loader reset method called");
    // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'mData'.
    if (mData != null) {
        releaseResources(mData);
        mData = null;
    }

    // The Loader is being reset, so we should stop monitoring for changes.
    if (mObserver != null) {
        try {
            getContext().unregisterReceiver(mObserver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mObserver = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCanceled(List<DemoItem> data) {
    // Attempt to cancel the current asynchronous load.
    super.onCanceled(data);

    // The load has been canceled, so we should release the resources
    // associated with 'data'.
    releaseResources(data);
}

private void releaseResources(List<DemoItem> data) {
    // For a simple List, there is nothing to do. For something like a Cursor, we
    // would close it in this method. All resources associated with the Loader
    // should be released here.
}

private BroadcastReceiver mObserver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Extract data included in the Intent
        //String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Log.d("receiver", "Got message: ");
    }
};
 }
```

**Error:**

```
Activity com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01.SampleLoader$1@75cf002 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                           android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01.SampleLoader$1@75cf002 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                               at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:918)
                                                                               at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:719)
                                                                               at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1172)
                                                                               at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1152)
                                                                               at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1146)
                                                                               at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:554)
                                                                               at com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01.SampleLoader.<init>(SampleLoader.java:29)
                                                                               at com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01.MainActivity.onCreateLoader(MainActivity.java:125)
                                                                               at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createLoader(LoaderManager.java:546)
                                                                               at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManager.java:555)
                                                                               at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManager.java:609)
                                                                               at com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Error 2**

```
IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: 
com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01.SampleLoader$1@4c0db59
09-07 12:39:07.496 22126-22126/com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01 W/System.err:     
at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:780)
09-07 12:39:07.496 22126-22126/com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01 W/System.err:     
at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1195)
09-07 12:39:07.496 22126-22126/com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01 W/System.err:     
at 
android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:576)
09-07 12:39:07.496 22126-22126/com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01 W/System.err:     
at com.aclass.asynctaskloader_01.SampleLoader.onReset(SampleLoader.java:116)
```

Comment: There is a problem with your `SampleLoader` class. It is not serializable.

Comment: Trying to save/restore a Loader like that is not the way to go. It's rather pointless, actually, even if you could get it to work. What was causing the crash originally?

Comment: if i not save this object like this it says null pointer exception on sample loader on configuration change

Comment: actualy loader have to handle the change but its not .sorry i am noob also.

Comment: Where exactly was it throwing that Exception? You should [edit] your question to show your code and stack trace from before you tried saving/restoring the Loader.

Comment: Check the edit it helps in identifying problem?

Comment: OK, if I'm following your description correctly, the `sampleLoader` field will end up null after a rotation because the `LoaderManager` won't necessarily need to create the `Loader` again, so `onCreateLoader()` doesn't get called, and `sampleLoader` is never initialized properly before your `Service` callback. The `initLoader()` method actually returns the `Loader` instance that it inits, whether it's created anew, or it's one that's already been created. In the `Activity`'s `onCreate()`, change that line to `sampleLoader = getLoaderManager().initLoader(...);`.

Comment: yes I think problem is little bit solving. I edit  some main activity code also in this post . also the line you said.now no crashing on home button and configuration changes. only one issue the updated data on list is only showing when activity restarts like on orientation change.service add data every after 15sec but its only append when activity restarts.

Comment: i just updated the post to clear more

Comment: Is `onLoadFinished()` being called each time? Did you override `onForceLoad()` correctly in `SampleLoader`?

Comment: no  onLoadFinished is only called when i changed the configuration. also their is no onForceLoad() method in my SampleLoader.

Comment: i uploaded the loader class above.

Comment: Loader methods should have run after service executes and add item in sqlite Database. but onLoadFinished called only when i changed the configuration and then data updated in screen.

Comment: Yeah, never mind the `onForceLoad()`. I just saw you're subclassing `AsyncTaskLoader`. I was asking if `onLoadFinished()` is being called each time the `Service` updates. Anyway, do some debugging to see exactly where it's failing. This has turned into a completely different question than what you originally posted. You really shouldn't drastically change your post, especially after people have posted answers.

Comment: It was my first post and the question in start is found out wrong because i just implemented it wrong. thanks for such help,problem is little bit minimized